# How to declare Hibernate model with denormalized table for performance

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on a business-application with Spring Boot 2 and Hibernate. Assume a simple entity:

```
@Entity
public class Project extends BaseEntity {
  @Column private String name;
  @Column private String address;
  ...
}
```

Here, `BaseEntity` is a `@MappedSuperclass` with some `@Id` and other general attributes. A requirement is that the `name` and `address` attribute should carry some "accuracy" attribute: Depending on where the data comes from, i.e. who enters it into the system, the accuracy is deemed higher or lower. Accuracy contains additional properties and should be historized, i.e. from an application point of view it is important to get accuracy values over time.

I am looking for the best way to model this. One desired property of the solution is that it should be possible to fetch the current actual value of `name`/`address` without joining some other table, in order to allow fast reads.

My initial idea was to define an `@Embeddable` like `ValueWithReferencedAccuracy<T>` that contains both a `T value` and a reference to some `AccuracyValue<T>`. However, since I have more than one attribute on `Project` that requires to be related to `AccuracyValue`, I would have to encode which *attribute* is related. That sounds quite bad. Also, there is the issue of keeping rows of `Project` and `AccuracyValue` in sync. I noticed that my problem is similar to that of auditing, and found that Envers is updating audit tables in event listeners.

It seems that the above solution is quite hacky, but I do not know how I would be able to save the actual value in the same table as the rest of the attributes, thus avoiding to join the accuracy table all the time.

Comment: If the accuracy value is "higher or lower", can't you just store it as a number alongside each column value?

Comment: In principle yes, though the accuracy (1) is not only a single number, but has more attributes itself and (2) I want to keep track of accuracy values over time, and this is considered relevant for the application, not only for auditing purposes.

Comment: The obvious solution is just to store the accuracy attributes in a separate table. Have you done some testing to show a significant improvement in performance by denormalizing here?

Comment: My idea is to store all accuracies (also historical values) in a separate table, since they will not be accessed so often. However the current value (not its accuracy) will be queried and fetched often. Sadly the entities I am looking at are much bigger. They might have 20 or more attributes with accuracies, which would lead to 1+20 queries just to get the current values. This is why I think that denormlization (duplication of the current value) is neceassary, even without any testing.

Comment: Hmm seems like it would be 1 query with 20 joins, not 1+20 queries to get the current values ... might still want to do some testing before settling for denormalization here

Comment: “*denormalization is necessary even without any testing*” - Modern SQL query optimizers are complex and powerful beasts. You should never make this assumption.